# Get all views in listview in setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-view

I am using below code to setcolor of a selected item of a listview. The rule is only one should be colored. But with below code if I select 2 views both get colored. Can you please help me get all other views in the listview so that when I click on certain view all other views i set to different color and the selected view i set a different color(Green in this case).
Please let me know if any other solution?

[image]

```
lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listf);
    lv.setAdapter(text![enter image description here][1]Adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView v = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.template_text);
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    });
```

Comment: are you using custom adapter?

Comment: Yes..I am using custom adapter. It houses textview and a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem using the below:
I put a loop where only the selected list item is set in RED whereas all others were set in Green, in this way only only one list item will be colored on selected.

```
lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listf);
lv.setAdapter(Adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
       if (position == i) 
       {
           parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
       } 
       else 
       {
          parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Dark_Green);
       }
    }
    TextView v = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.template_text);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you told you are not able to change adapter code, you can prefer solution 2.

**Solution 1:** Create one variable `int selectedPosition` and method `setSelected` in your adapter class

```
int selectedPosition = -1;
public void setSelected(int position)
{
     selectedPosition = position;
     notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

Edit `getView()` of the adapter class and include following code

```
if(selectedPosition==position)
{
     templateTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
else templateTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);//  default textView color
```

**Solution 2:** keep reference of previously selected textView as well each time change the color of currently selected textview to green andd previous one to blue

```
TextView previousSelected = null;
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(previousSelected!=null)
             previousSelected.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        TextView v = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.template_text);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        previousSelected = v;
    }
});
```

Comment: I cant put it in adapter class due to some reasons. I have to put in Onitemclicklistener itself which is outside Adapter class.

Comment: What reason can you explain a bit?

Comment: Pr38y forgot how to use all this. In onItemClick: adapter.setSelected(position); or listView.getAdapter().setSelected(position);

Comment: i want all other views other than the selected position so that i change the color of all items to blue and later set the color of only one selected item to green.

Comment: @greenapps thanks buddy. how can I forget this. It seems I have over-engineered it :P

Comment: @Pr38y, the second solution is bad. If the user scrolls the listview all is gone. Stick to the first one.